# How to filter a string from an array with different types of elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to return an array with just string elements from an array that different types of elements.

I tried using the filter method to extract the elements that are a string

This is what I did

```js
const newArray = [3, 'string A', 9, 'string B'];

console.log(
  newArray.filter((element) => element === String)
)
```

It returned an empty array `[]`. My expected output is:

```
['string A', 'string B']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like
return newArray.filter((element) => typeof element === 'string');
Now you'll get your desired solution
i.e:['string A', 'string B']

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

```js
const arr = [3, 'string A', 9, 'string B'];

const out = arr.filter(el => typeof el === 'string');

console.log(out);
```